# How can i run my script multiple time by using TestNG framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using POM framework for automating my site.I need to execute all @Test methods including @BeforeClass and @AfterClass attributes in my script for number of times by using 'for' loop.I tried it in many ways but i didn't get required output.By using jUnit I did it.But I want it by using TestNG.Please help me.

Comment: Please post your code and the error you are getting after execution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the invocation count to execute the script multiple times.  Example:

```
    @Test(invocationCount=3)
    public void m2(){
        System.out.println("execute method 2");
    }
```

The above method will be invoked 3 times. Are you expecting the same or something different?

Comment: I need to execute all Test's in a class including BeforeClass and AfterClass annotations multiple times

Comment: Possibly you can explore @Factory annotation for your requirement. Here is the link for your reference. You can have beforeclass, afterclass and have the invocation counter for your test methods. All you need to do is to create an object. Follow the below link  [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-factory-annotation-tutorial/)

Comment: Have a method and use the for loop.

Comment: Yes.I need to execute a whole class(including Test's, BeforeMethod, AfterMethod annotations) multiple times by using 'for' loop in TestNg

Answer (score 0):

You can provide invocationCount=n(number of times you want to run your test method) in the @Test

```
@Test(invocationCount=2)
public void Test1(){
System.out.println("This is a Test");
}
```

Comment: Not only one Test, i need to execute all Tests,BeforeClass and AfterClass annotations more times